# How To Just Print Columns Names From a MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

How do you print out all the column names of a table. Just like a simple, for loop type printing out. I'm trying a wacky thing and checking against the column names will be useful. 
This may sound like a similar question to others, but either I'm too stupid or I just haven't found my answer.

Simplifcation - If there are 3 columns in the table, I want to just print them out like

```
column1
column2
column3
```

More Explanation I should have added before. I'm using php to run a website that stores data into a database. I want to try a theory that involves using the column names of a table in order to change the values in that table.

@Michael -

```
$SQL = "SELECT column_name from information_schema.columns where 
table_schema = "db1.com" and table_name = "users" ";
```

Thank you all for your help. However I have given up on trying this method. Thank you for all the responses

Comment: Typing your title in Google shows several pages, including Stack Exchange pages, that answer your question exactly. Did you try that? What did you not understand about the answers?

Comment: I did try that. All of them go off topic and use code that seems too complicated to just simply work the way I want it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
  FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
  WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdatabasename' 
  AND `TABLE_NAME`='yourtablename';
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This didn't seem to break it. However I have given up on trying this method. Thank you for all the responses

Comment: desc {table_name} - is the easiest way of selecting all the columns from a table.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the answer is the longer one. The right answer for this is `describe {table_name}`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema = "your_database_name" and table_name = "your_table_name";
```

Comment: I tried this and it breaks the code for some reason

Comment: @Excal If you could, please explain how suggested answers do or do not help. Simply saying that it doesn't work doesn't provide any insight to provide you with a better answer.

Comment: @MichaelDunlap my apologies. When I try to do $SQL = 'Select etc.' , the webpage goes blank, meaning the line broke somewhere for it to not display anything

Comment: @Excal Can you please share the code exactly as you tried it as an edit to your original question?